# Spring Integration Feed Inbound Channel Adapter to DB and Kafka

Tags: spring-integration

I am refactoring some of my Spring Integration RSS feed code which uses feed inbound channel adaptor to a microservice. I want the feeds to be stored internally in a mongodb database (in case of failures, audit etc) and also to write the feed (in JSON) to a kafka topic for onward processing.

How do I do this with Spring Integration? Do I need a pub/subscribe queue with two handlers?

Any example code using Java DSL would be most helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you need pub/sub for such a use-case, but definitely you can use `QueueChannel` in between Feed Inbound Channel Adapter and Kafka Outbound Channel Adapter. That `QueueChannel` can really be supplied with the `MongoDbChannelMessageStore` for persistence in case of failures.

The Java DSL sample is like this:

```
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow feedFlow(MongoDbChannelMessageStore messageStore) {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(Feed.inboundAdapter(...),
                        e -> e.poller(p -> p.fixedDelay(1000)))
                .channel(c -> c.queue(messageStore, "entries"))
                .handle(Kafka.outboundChannelAdapter(...), 
                        e -> e.poller(p -> p.fixedDelay(1000)))
                .get();
    }
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.3.RELEASE/reference/html/feed.html#feed-java-configuration

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.3.RELEASE/reference/html/mongodb.html#mongodb-priority-channel-message-store

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.1.4.RELEASE/reference/html/_spring_integration.html#si-outbound

Comment: Thanks Artem, I'll give this a whirl.

Comment: Hi Artem, is there any way for MongoDbChannelMessageStore to store the feeds in json instead of binary? Also how would you replay the messages in case of failure?